# proxy error after installing Tor browser on Mac

Tags: configuration

After installing the Tor browser from Tor project on my Mac, I got the following error when I attempted to go to a web site:

> The proxy server is refusing connections . 
>   Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that can't be found . 
>   check proxy settings ...

My settings:

> Manual settings
>   SOCKS Host 127.0.0.1 Port: 9150
>   SocksV5 is checked, remote DNS is checked

I tried several other options to no avail.
How do I know what to use here?

Comment: Onion Menu -> Network Settings -> Copy Tor Log to Clipboard and add it to your question, please.

Comment: I could not find onion menu->network settings->Tor log.

Comment: I just downloaded the Tor Browser . Do I need to download Tor also?

Comment: There should be an onion icon to the left of the address bar, if it's not there it's possible that something went wrong with the installation or the download didn't complete. did you verify the signature?

Comment: I did not see the onion icon. I started the verification process and got up to the point where I needed the .asc file. I am not sure how to download that file but it is now a mute point because I got the Tor browser to work by repeating the download process. This time I got the step to choose how to connect to the internet - I selected direct connection to the Tor network. I can now use the Tor browser. Thanks for your help.